# Can I name a new object in an array using a variable in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a new nested array with the name of a variable. Is this possible?

data example:

```
[{
    varname {
         name: person1name;
         events : [{
             firstName: person1name,
             name: event1name,
             date: date1
             },{
             firstName: person2name,
             name: event2name,
             date: date2
             }
         ]
    }
}]
```

code:

```
$scope.multiEvents = []

var eventCategory = $scope.event.name

$scope.multiEvents.eventCategory.name = $scope.event.firstName;
$scope.multiEvents.eventCategory.events.push($scope.event);
$scope.multiEvents.eventCategory.events.push($scope.event2);
```

Comment: So what's the problem you're experiencing with this? Does it not work when you run it?

Comment: Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.multiEvents.eventCategory.name = $scope.event.firstName')

Comment: What do you mean by "Name an array"?

Comment: Basically, I think it's saying eventCategory is undefined, even though I just defined it. I don't think I'm creating an object with that name.

Comment: I want to be able to create an object named whatever $scope.event.name is equal to

Comment: @dangnelson Try setting eventCategory = $eval($scope.event.name). Make sure to include the $eval service in your controller.

Comment: You can't create an object "named" after the value of something else. You name your objects explicitly in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing this:

```
$scope.multiEvents = [];
$scope.multiEvent = {};
$scope.multiEvent.events = [];

$scope.multiEvent.name = $scope.event.firstName;
$scope.multiEvent.events.push($scope.event);
$scope.multiEvent.events.push($scope.event2);

$scope.multiEvents.push($scope.multiEvent);
```

I think I was just confused.